# Chromatic Number and Odd Cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

It's a well known fact that a graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no odd cycles. This is an interesting generalization:
 Call a sub-graph *nice* if it has an odd number of vertices (more than 1) and it contains a Hamiltonian cycle. Assume that a graph G has at most $2^k-k-2$ *nice* sub-graphs. Prove that $\chi(G)\le k$.

My first attempt to solve the problem was to apply the breadth-first search algorithm (BFS) on the graph. This is actually the standard way for verifying the case $k=2$. Now notice that G is partitioned into several rows (the number of a row determines its distance with the root) and if $e=\{u,v\}$ is an edge such that $u$ and $v$ are in the same row (we call such $e$ an *inner* edge) , by tracing back $u$ and $v$ through upper rows we finally arrive at a common vertex; Hence each inner edge determines a *nice* sub-graph uniquely (this map is not necessarily surjective). So there are at most $2^k-k-2$ *inner* edges. This upper bound on the number of inner edges might be helpful for coloring the vertices with $k$ colors.
Unfortunately I'm stuck here. I was wondering if someone could help me to continue this idea. Besides, I've seen another approach for the problem; I just want to follow my own idea...
Thanks in advance.